# Collapse tuple column by first tuple element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, tuples

I have this dataset:

```
r = pd.DataFrame({'duplicates': [ [("007", "us1", "us2", 7, 1),  ("001", "us1", "us2", 9, 8), ("009", "us1", "us2", 28, 27)], ("007", "us2", "us1", 8, 15), ("009", "us4", "us1", 29, 30), ("009", "us4", "us1", 29, 30)], 
     'id': ["b", 'c', 'b', "c"]})

duplicates                                                                 id
0   [(007, us1, us2, 7, 1), (001, us1, us2, 9, 8), (009, us1, us2, 28, 27)] b
1   (007, us2, us1, 8, 15)  c
2   (009, us4, us1, 29, 30) b
3   (009, us4, us1, 29, 30) c
```

Here the tuples are grouped based on the us1, us2 [...] order. So the tuples are in the same row if they have the same 'id' and the same sequence of users. On the first, line, for example, us2 accessed record 007 on the time 7. Also, us1 accessed record 007 on the time 01.

What I want is to have this:

```
j = pd.DataFrame({'duplicates': [ ("007", ['us2', 'us1', 'us2', 'us1'], 1, 7, 8, 15),  ("001", ['us2', 'us1'], 8, 9), ("009", ['us2', 'us1', 'us4', 'us1'], 27, 28, 29, 30), ("009", ['us4', 'us1'], 29, 30)], 
     'id': ["b", "b", 'b', "c"]})

     duplicates                                id
0   (007, [us2, us1, us2, us1], 1, 7, 8, 15)    b
1   (001, [us2, us1], 8, 9) b
2   (009, [us2, us1, us4, us1], 27, 28, 29, 30) b
3   (009, [us4, us1], 29, 30)   c
```

On this case I want to group by id and by the first parts of the tuple. As an example, of the first row, I've used '007' and the 'id' as the keys and then I add the users based on the time access. So us2 is before us1 because us2 accessed on the time 1 and us1 accessed on the time 7, and 1 < 7.

This is what I have until now, but it's very far away of the result, and I don't know what do to:

```
r.explode('duplicates').groupby(['id',  r['duplicates'].str[0]])['duplicates'].apply(list).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```